# Doing a Discrete Fourier Transformed followed by an Inverse Discrete Fourier Transform does not produce the original values on Accelerate vDSP

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, fft

I have a series of discrete values. So, I have no imaginary values for the input part. I am doing a Discrete Fourier Transform to these values and performing an Inverse Discrete Fourier Transform, to get the same values back. The idea was to test if vDSP from Accelerate Framework was working as expected, cause the documentation is a piece of crap and you have to figure it out by yourself.

Consider the following code

```
  lazy var DFTSetupForward: vDSP_DFT_Setup = {
    guard let setup = vDSP_DFT_zop_CreateSetupD(
      nil,
      vDSP_Length(self.numSamples),
      vDSP_DFT_Direction.FORWARD) else {
        fatalError("can't create vDSP_DFT_Setup")
    }
    return setup
  }()

  lazy var DFTSetupInverse: vDSP_DFT_Setup = {
    guard let setup = vDSP_DFT_zop_CreateSetupD(
      nil,
      vDSP_Length(self.numSamples),
      vDSP_DFT_Direction.INVERSE) else {
        fatalError("can't create vDSP_DFT_Setup")
    }
    return setup
  }()
 func discreteFourierTransform (_ valores:[Double] = []) -> ([Double], [Double]) {
    let numeroDados = valores.count

    let inputImag  = Array<Double>(repeating:0.0, count:numeroDados)
    var outputReal = Array<Double>(repeating:0.0, count:numeroDados)
    var outputImag = Array<Double>(repeating:0.0, count:numeroDados)

    vDSP_DFT_ExecuteD(DFTSetupForward, valores, inputImag, &outputReal, &outputImag)
    return (outputReal, outputImag)
  }


  // faz a DISCRETE FOURIER TRANSFORM DOUBLE
  // a saída corresponde aos vetores reais e imaginários
  func discreteFourierTransformInverse (_ valoresReais:[Double] = [],
                                        _ valoresImaginarios:[Double] = []) -> ([Double], [Double]) {
    let numeroDados = valoresReais.count

    var outputReal = Array<Double>(repeating:0.0, count:numeroDados)
    var outputImag = Array<Double>(repeating:0.0, count:numeroDados)

    vDSP_DFT_ExecuteD(DFTSetupInverse, valoresReais, valoresImaginarios, &outputReal, &outputImag)
    return (outputReal, outputImag)
  }
```

and later these calls

```
let (outputDFTreal, outputDFTImaginario ) = self.discreteFourierTransform(normalizedData)

let (sinalRealX, sinalImaginarioX ) = self.discreteFourierTransformInverse(outputDFTreal, outputDFTImaginario)
```

or in other words, I am taking the results of the Fourier Transform from the first `let` and injecting them into the Inverse Fourier Transform. I expect `sinalRealX` to be equal to the original data, that in this case is `normalizedData` and also expect `signalImaginarioX` to be all zeros.

But the values are completely different!

What is going on?

Comment: Amen to the documentation comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't expect the IDFT to return the normalized values. You should expect it to return the orginal (pre-normalize) values, which I believe it does (within computational error):

```
let fft = FFT()
let data = Array(stride(from: 0.0, to: Double(fft.numSamples), by: 1))
let normalizedData = data.map{ $0/Double(fft.numSamples) }
let (outputDFTreal, outputDFTImaginario ) = fft.discreteFourierTransform(normalizedData)
let (sinalRealX, sinalImaginarioX ) = fft.discreteFourierTransformInverse(outputDFTreal, outputDFTImaginario)
print(data)
print(sinalRealX)
print(sinalImaginarioX)

let zeros = Array(repeating: 0.0, count: data.count)
func avgerr(_ a: [Double], _ b: [Double]) -> Double {
    return zip(a, b).map { abs($0 - $1) }.reduce(0, +) / Double(a.count)
}

avgerr(data, sinalRealX)  // 2.442490654175344e-15
avgerr(zeros, sinalImaginarioX) // 2.602442788260593e-15
```

Comment: yes, the problem appears to be related to the normalization, but the imaginary part comes with all numbers `x10^-19` that I suppose are zeros but the real part are not exactly the same values as before. If I do the same operation using [this page](http://scistatcalc.blogspot.com/2013/12/fft-calculator.html) the results are the same.

Comment: What do you mean "are not exactly the same values as before?" To what amount of error? You should expect some error when doing floating point math. How many significant digits is that website producing, and how many significant digits are you comparing? (The page you linked seems to correct to 10^-6. My results are correct to 10^-15.)

Comment: The website produces the same exact original values. These routines produce values that are, at least, 20% off. I got the idea. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Floating point numbers are an approximation. And 10^-19 is approximately zero, relative to cos(0), in double precision floating-point arithmetic.

So you did get all zeros in the result.